# All shapes/entities showing up as black in A-Frame scenes

Tags: android, html, aframe

When viewing A-frame examples with Chrome or Firefox on a mobile Android device, all shapes appear black. This is the same whether in VR-mode or not. The background does have color.

When viewing the same examples in the same browsers on a different mobile Android device, the colors render without issue. Why is that?

Comment: Can you be more specific about used phone, android version, examples you're running? The examples on aframe.io run without issue on a Pixel2.

Comment: The issue is occurring with multiple brand-new "Samsung Galaxy J3 Mission" (SM-J327VPP) phones running Android 7.0.

My personal phone is also a J3, but it's SM-J327T. It is also running Android 7.0. The issue is not occurring on my device.

Comment: Having the same issue on an LG Aristo (LG-M210) running Android 7.0 (Jan 1, 2018 security patch)

Comment: Looks like there's a Github issue for this problem here: https://github.com/aframevr/aframe/issues/3523

Comment: This seems to be a three.js problem, rather than something A-frame-specific. Does the standard mesh materal demo work for you? https://threejs.org/docs/scenes/material-browser.html#MeshStandardMaterial  (it doesn't for me)

Comment: Filed as a three.js issue here: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/14137